# Catching exceptions thrown without try/catch

Tags: c++, exception, error-handling, diagnostics

I recall reading about how exceptions could be caught without the use of try/catch. Basically when an exception is thrown such as "Unhandled exception" via derefencing a null pointer, there would be a process that is triggered even when a try/catch is not coded for the exception. I believe it had something to do with a top level library that you write then include in your code. Unfortunately documentation on such a method seems to be non-existent but I have seen/heard of such a method being done before. Could someone please explain how this is done?

Comment: On what platform? For what exceptions? On Windows there's a whole underlying SEH mechanism.

Comment: @bmargulies: I am looking into "SetUnhandledExceptionFilter", however, there is little to no documention on this. Ther is also no concrete example of this working, do you know of any?

Comment: MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680634(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I can't offer much help with SEH.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C++, dereferencing a null pointer causes undefined behavior, which does not necessarily imply that an exception is thrown. On Unix systems, for example, a SIGSEGV signal is raised instead.

On Windows, access violations raise a [SEH](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680657%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) exception. SEH exceptions are not the same as C++ exception; they are handled using [`__try/__except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s58ftw19%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) statements (as opposed to `try/catch` statements). An unhandled SEH exception invokes unhandled exception filter, which you can set using [`SetUnhandledExceptionFilter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680634%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

LONG WINAPI MyFilter(EXCEPTION_POINTERS * /*ExceptionInfo*/)
{
    std::cout << "An uncaught exception was detected!\n";

    // Ultimately causes Windows Error Reporting to be invoked.
    // Use EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER to silently terminate the application.
    return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH;
}

int main()
{
    SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(MyFilter);
    *(char volatile *)0 = 0;
}
```

Comment: "dereferencing a null pointer" was simply an example of an exception that was thrown, i will look into SetUnhandledExceptionFilter

Comment: Note that Visual Studio provides options to allow SEH exceptions to be handled by C++ `try`/`catch`. If this option is used such exceptions are caught in `catch ( ... )` (and only that).

Comment: @avakar: I am looking into "SetUnhandledExceptionFilter", however, there is little to no documention on this. Ther is also no concrete example of this working, do you know of any?

Comment: @Adam Badura: So in order to make "SetUnhandledExceptionFilter" work, I need to use try/catch?

Comment: @judeclarke, not at all, you just call `SetUnhandledExceptionFilter` with your handler and then if an exception escapes main function without being caught, the handler will be called.

Comment: @judeclarke, I;ve added an example. Note that there actually is a lot of documentation, just follow the link in the article. You'll probably need to read the the whole chapter on SEH to make sense of it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680657%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: @avakar: hmm, I have been reading it and I took a look at your example and the function "MyFilter" is not being entered. Do you happen to know why?

Comment: @judeclarke, probably because you're running the example in the debugger, which will intercept the exception before it enters the filter. Run it stand-alone and observe the output. I haven't found a way to debug the filter directly.

Answer (score 2):

You may be thinking of the Windows [Structured Exception Handling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680657%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) mechanism. With full C++ try/catch semantics supported, I personally haven't found any reasonable use case for it.

Comment: I can - if you have some fatal exceptions, you want to crash the app, preferably generating a minidump in the process. If you don't have DrWatson or NTSD running, you can put your own minidump routine in. The minidump can then be post-mortem debugged to find out where and why it went bang.

Comment: @gbjbaanb: Do you happen to have an example of how you did this? Or where you learned to do this?

Comment: I am looking into "SetUnhandledExceptionFilter", however, there is little to no documention on this. Ther is also no concrete example of this working, do you know of any?

Answer (score 1):

That's an operating system implementation detail, dereferencing a null pointer doesn't generate a C++ exception.  On Windows that generates an SEH exception, the MSVC compiler lets you handle them with the non-standard __try and __except keywords.  On *nix that generates a signal, you use the functions in the signal.h header file.