# What does throw do when not in used with try and catch?

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch, throw

What does `throw` do when not used with try and catch? Like:

```
 if (IsEmpty()) throw "Stack is empty, Cannot delete";
```

Does it get printed in console?

But when `throw` contains some int or char as its arguments, it is thrown to catch; what happens in this case?

Comment: It crashes your program :-)

Comment: Same thing as an uncaught `std::exception &`.

Comment: Same thing as *any* uncaught exception; the default handler outside of `main()`will most-assuredly terminate your process.

Answer (score 2):

The C++ runtime will have something along the lines of (this is NOT exactly how it looks, but you can think of it as working this way, unless you are working on something very special):

```
void BeforeMain()
{
     try
     {
        int res = main();
        exit(res);
     } 
     catch(...)
     {
         cout << "Unhandled exception. Terminating..." << endl;
         terminate();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are allowed to do that, and it will not be caught anywhere within your code if you have not put an explicit try catch block. 
Windows uses a SEH mechanism to handle , where you could have an uncaught exception filter to figure out about the same

See this post for more details
[Catching exceptions thrown without try/catch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6004763/catching-exceptions-thrown-without-try-catch)